# Sql cache dependency using EntLib caching block

Tags: sql, caching, dependencies

how to implement sql cache dependency using Enterprise library application block?

Answer (score 2):

David Hayden has a article/blog post on his site for how to do this:

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/04/30/2930.aspx